# JavaScript Encoding?

Tags: javascript, regex, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm having a little trouble with a JavaScript file not loading correctly on different computers. I have this line in my JavaScript file:

```
var URL_REGEXP = /\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/gi;
```

It loads fine on my computer, but on a friends computer with Chinese as its operating system language, the browser shows a JavaScript error. On debugging the code, I found this line has been served as this:

```
var URL_REGEXP = /\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?芦禄鈥溾€濃€樷€橾))/gi;
```

Note the random characters at the end of this line.

I'm guessing it is an encoding problem... any ideas on how to solve this? Should I be encoding my JavaScript files in UTF8 or something? If so, how? Do I save the file with this encoding or is there a JavaScript tag I can use? I am already using the HTML meta content-type tag that serves the character-encoding as utf-8.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you specifying a charset in your `<script>` tag? That will probably help. Check out the `charset` attribute.

Comment: I have set the charset to UTF8 and also saved the file telling it explicitly to encode it in UTF8 (with signature) code page - 650001

Comment: Also, my webserver is configured to serve all content type as UTF8 and I have added the meta charset tag to the HTML document behind that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the comments/answers. The solution I found that worked was to save the JavaScript file explicitly (using any code editor) in UTF-8 format. In addition, explicitly specify the charset in every script tag you reference to this script.

For example, if you have `example.js`:

First, save it with UTF-8 encoding (with signature, codepage 650001).
Then, when you reference it with a script tag: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="/example.js"></script>`.

This is useful when your script contains unicode characters, such as searching for Chinese text etc.

Answer (score 0):

See [unicode in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) :

> To match a specific Unicode code point, use \uFFFF where FFFF is the hexadecimal number of the code point you want to match.

So you should replace `«»“”‘’` by `\u00AB\u00BB\u201C\u201D\u2018\u2019` for characters' code see the [UTF-8 character table](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128).